# in python how can i get input in sublime?

Tags: python-3.x, input, sublimetext3

while getting the user input 
ex.
a=input("Enter the number or string ")
when i execute this statement it takes to me an infinite loop after which nothing is executed in the sublime.
which setting or features i need to embed into sublime for getting the input?

Answer (score 0):

install [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) (documentation on how to install it on the github link) to use it :

go to : Tools>SublimeREPL>Python>Python - RUN current file

Answer (score 0):

Sublime-text doesn't allow users to give input to the program but you can make a new Python build system to allow you to give input.

- Go to **Tools**>>**Build System**>>**New Build System**
- Paste the below code in the file and **Save** the file.

-

```
{
   "shell_cmd": "gnome-terminal -- bash -c \"python3 -u $file;echo;echo Press Enter to exit...;read\"",
   "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.python",

}
```

Save the file and Select build using **Ctrl+Shift+B**

When you will execute your program using **Ctrl+B** this will run the program in a terminal and where will be able to give input.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can try this also. It will work well.

- Go to **Tools**>>**Build System**>>**New Build System**
- Paste it

---

```
{
    "file_regex": "^\\s*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "shell": true,
    "selector": "source.py,source.pyhton",
    "shell_cmd": "gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'python3 $file;echo;echo -e \"\\e[107m \\e[92m \\e[1m \\e[5mPress ENTER to continue\";read line;exit'", // for gnome-terminal 
}
```

---

Let, you will save the file python3.sublime-build. So, after saving you can see the option

- **Tools**>>**Build Systems**>>**python3**

So, mark it and just press **Ctrl+B** every time.

And enjoy !!!!!!!!